# Signature Scanner Value not correct

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory, external, reverse-engineering

I'm learning about signature scanning and having some problems. My code is sort of ugly but it should work,,, can't understand how to fix my problem. My main function memory.findSignature() in my main returns a garbage value and therefor my when i read and give RemoteHealth a value it is also garbage.

Main:

```
    LPCSTR signature = "\x48\x4A\x85\x2A\x44\x49";
LPCSTR mask = "xxxxxx";
uintptr_t healthAddr = memory.findSignature(CS.client.dwBase, CS.client.dwSize, signature, mask);
int RemoteHealth = memory.readAddress<int>(healthAddr);
std::cout << "value:" << std::hex << RemoteHealth <<   " address:" << healthAddr <<std::endl;
```

memory.h:

```
        bool memoryCompare(const byte* data, const byte* mask, const char* szMask) {
    for (; *szMask; ++szMask, ++data, ++mask) {
        if (*szMask == 'x' && *data != *mask) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

uintptr_t findSignature(uintptr_t sigStart, uintptr_t sigSize, const char* signature, const char* mask) {
    byte* data = new byte[sigSize];
    SIZE_T bytesRead;

    ReadProcessMemory(procHandle, (LPVOID)sigStart, data, sigSize, &bytesRead);
    for (uintptr_t i = 0; i < sigSize; i++) {
        if (this->memoryCompare((const byte*)(data + i), (const byte*)signature, mask)) {
            delete[] data;
            return sigStart + i;
        }
    }
    delete[] data;
    return NULL;
}
```

I don't know what would explain this but i know the issue is in one of my two memory functions...

```
http://prntscr.com/mqpx9h
http://prntscr.com/mqpz85
http://prntscr.com/mqpzqm
```

the return in memoryCompare are flipped, but the values still are garbage in read.... the address just reads as first in module :/